# Image with TouchableOpacity onpress not working in react native

Tags: image, react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

I am new to react native development. In my application in one screen I have image click. So i have taken image inside touchable opacity and wrote onpress method to that touchable opacity. But onpress is not working. But i have written the same code to another image, but this one is working.

This is the code

```
mport React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View,TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet,StatusBar,Image} from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        title: `Welcome`,
        header: null,
      }
    };

    render() {
      const { state, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content"
          backgroundColor="#2f5597"
        />
             <View style={{backgroundColor: "#fff",padding: 10}}>
                 <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_visa.png')} style={{marginLeft: -10}}></Image>
                 <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.backArrow()} style={styles.signoutContainer}> 
                    <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_Signout.png')} style={styles.signOutImage}></Image>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>

             <View style={{backgroundColor: "#2f5597",flexDirection: 'row',alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.backArrow()} style={{padding: 12.5,justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:"#2f5597"}}>
                   <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_arrow_white.png')} style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start',alignSelf: 'center',alignContent: 'center'}}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{padding: 10,color:'#fff', backgroundColor:"#2f5597", fontSize: 18,fontWeight: "bold", paddingLeft: 5,alignSelf: 'center'}}>Confirm payment</Text>
                <View style={styles.signoutContainer}> 
                    <Text style={{color: '#fff',alignSelf: 'flex-end',marginRight: 30}}>743509-001</Text>
                 </View>
             </View>

             <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 30, marginTop: 30}}>
               <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_right.png')} style={{height: 48, width: 56}}></Image>
               <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center',fontSize: 20,color: '#000',marginLeft: 10}}>Payment Successful</Text>
             </View>
             <Text style={{marginLeft: 30,marginTop: 10,color: '#000',fontSize: 14}}>Thank you for your payment.</Text>
             <Text style={{marginLeft: 30,marginTop: 10,color: '#000',fontSize: 14,textAlign: "justify", marginRight: 30}}>This page serves as your receipt and provides you with the confirmation number ****** that can be used for further reference. </Text>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={this.login}
              style={[styles.btn]}>
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>MAKE ANOTHER PAYMENT</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

        </View>
      );
    }
    login=()=>{
      console.log('Hi button click');
      alert("make another payment......");
    }
    backArrow=()=>{
      // alert("Go to account list......");
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
    }
  }


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    MainContainer :{
         backgroundColor: "#fff",
         // Setting up View inside content in Vertically center.
           justifyContent: 'center',
           flex:1,
           margin: 0
         },
         signoutContainer: {
          flex: 1,  
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          alignItems: 'center'
         },
         numberContainer: {
          flex: 1,  
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#fff000'
         },
         signOutImage:{
          alignSelf: 'flex-end',
          width: 35,
          height: 35,
         },
         buttonContainer: {
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#FFF',
         },

         btn:{
           alignSelf: 'stretch',
           borderRadius: 6,
           backgroundColor: '#2f5597',
           padding: 10,
           marginTop: 30,
           marginLeft: 30,
           marginRight: 30,
           alignItems: 'center',
         }
  });
```

This is the screenshot of above code.

[image]

Here left arrow image click working fine. I have written same onprees to that grey image. But grey image click not working. Here i tried both ways but not working.

```
onPress={() => this.backArrow()}
onPress={this.login}
```

So please guide me how to solve this issue. Thanks In Advance..

Comment: Which onPress is not working?

Answer (score 3):

sorry for late response,
It is unable to get flex because parent view doesn't contain any flex. so try this:-

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "#fff",padding: 10, flex:1}}>
                 <Image source={require('./chnIcon.png')} style={{marginLeft: -10}}></Image>
                 <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.backArrow()} style={styles.signoutContainer}> 
                    <Image source={require('./calendar_icon.png')} style={styles.signOutImage}></Image>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
```

or remove flex:1 from Touchable Opacity style. Now it will work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to binding issue .  try binding the onclick method like below

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);    
  }
```

Then call this function as

```
onPress={this.login}
```

Comment: but the same thing working fine for back arrow image, but not working for grey image. i don't know the reason here

Comment: any update, here one image click working, but the same code another image click not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try just to put *onPress={this.backArrow}*

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is with design, if i changed the design, it is working fine. here i have changed flex-direction: 'row'

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "#fff",padding: 10,*flexDirection: 'row'*}}>
                 <Image source={require('../../app/images/logo_SEDC_110n40.png')} style={{marginLeft: -10}}></Image>
                 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.logout} style={styles.signoutContainer}> 
                    <Image source={require('../../app/images/ic_Signout.png')} style={styles.signOutImage}></Image>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
```